# Phabricator - How to Review a Merge

Tags: git, merge, phabricator

We have two branches, and I want to merge the tip of one onto the other.
Like any code change, this needs to be reviewed in Phabricator/Differential.

It all seems like very normal workflow to me, but I can't figure out how to get it done.

### The Merge We Do

We have two branches - `master` and `beta`. Most development is done on `master`.
Occasionally, we merge from `master` to `beta`.
With plain git, we would do this:

```
% git checkout beta
% git merge master
% git commit
% git push
```

But with Phabricator, we can't just do `git push` (and don't want to - code review is important).

### Problem with `arc diff`

I do the merge as above, but replace `git push` with `arc diff`.

First, the message it offers to use is the commit message of one of the commits I've merged. This isn't a good message, so I replace it with `merge master into beta`.

Next, I get this message:

```
You don't own revision D97: "Some change".
Normally, you should only update revisions you own. You can "Commandeer"
this revision from the web interface if you want to become the owner.

Update this revision anyway? [y/N]
```

Revision `D97` is a change which was already landed into `master`. I certainly don't want to commandeer it. I answer no and `arc diff` exits.

Running `arc diff --create` behaves the same.

### Problem with `arc land`

I can use `arc diff --preview` to create a diff, and then a revision from the web UI. I don't know if it's a good idea, but I can proceed with the review.

Afrer the patch is approved, `arc land` squashes all changes into one commit. For normal development, I agree with the rationale - I want one change to enter as one commit.

But here the result is awful - there's no record of a merge between `master` and `beta`. It seems as if all `master`'s changes were rewritten over `beta`. Future merges will suffer because the merge isn't recorded.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have found a workaround for the `arc diff` step, and I can't see a better one unfortunately.

`arc land --merge` will land the changes as a merge instead of squash.

Comment: Thanks. I don't think my workaround really works. I now see that I didn't describe it exactly right - `arc land` in the clone where I did `arc diff` doesn't work, because the revision wasn't created there. I can run `arc patch`, but it squashes the commits, so a merge won't be recorded regardless of how `arc land` works.

Comment: Do you really want to review commits again that were already reviewed? If not, you might be better using `git rebase master` instead of `git merge master` in your workflow.  Probably you only need to review the manual conflict resolution that was required to complete the merge?

Comment: It's important to me that a merge will be recorded. If I understand correctly, `git rebase` won't do this. It's very important to review the merge - not to review commits already reviewed, but to assure that they were merged properly. Once I have a revision in Phabricator, the reviewer can do `arc patch` and verify whatever is needed.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I managed to get a full solution, which includes your answer and some more. See my answer if you're interested.

Answer (score 1):

I have a method that works, end to end. It's quite annoying.

1. Merge in git - a normal merge.
2. Create diff with `arc diff --preview`.
3. Go to the link printed by the last command and create a revision based on the diff.
4. A reviewer can now review the change. To review properly, he'll need to run `arc patch` and compare the various related versions (source branch, target branch, merge result, common ancestor).
5. Land the diff with `arc land --merge --revision D123`. `--merge` (as suggested in [JSON's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41051310/1111371) prevents squashing the commits, `--revision` prevents confusion with the revisions used to land the merged content.

I didn't check what happens if the reviewer requests changes, and another `arc diff` is needed before I can land.